# What are the latest findings on the topology and size of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, topology, cosmic-microwave-background

The paper

> G. Aslanyan & A.V. Manohar, *The Topology and Size of the Universe from the Cosmic Microwave Background,* [JCAP 06 (2012) 003](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1475-7516/2012/06/003), [arXiv:1104.0015](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.0015),

uses the 7-year WMAP data. Has any additional checking been done on newer data (e.g. Planck)?  Has other work superseded this result, through criticism or improved calculations?

Comment: I think that Planck data did not changed so much the situation. Anyway, I wait for answers to your question.

Comment: Did you also notice this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03884 what is interesting is that more complex shapes seem still not ruled out, e.g. flat hypertorus.

Answer (score 2):

The latest constraint on the curvature of the universe comes from the [Planck Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)) which indicates that the universe is very flat today.

Comment: "Flat" does not mean "topologicially trivial" or "finite volume", though.